# The floor of a product of fractions

Tags: inequality, contest-math, fractions, products, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Evaluate: $ \displaystyle  \Bigg \lfloor \prod_{n=0}^{248} \frac{33+8n}{29+8n} \Bigg \rfloor= \Bigg \lfloor \frac{33}{29} \times \frac{41}{37} \times \frac{49}{45} \times\ ...\ \times \frac{2009}{2005} \times \frac{2017}{2013} \Bigg \rfloor $

I tried to tackle this problem by first trying to place bounds on the product itself using various inequalities such as AM-GM and Cauchy-Schwarz. I did get somewhere and I started to get hopeful but it didn't quite work out. It seemed as if I could place an upper bound but not a lower bound. Maybe Rearrangement/Muirhead/Chebyshev/Holder's inequalities could help but I haven't tried those yet, as a matter of fact I don't think I remember many of them either. Any help on this will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest that this question should be closed for now.The OP is abusing the site by copying questions from Brilliant.org and asking for solutions and thereby getting his/her rating up on Brilliant.org.

Comment: "_Many of the questions on Brilliant are themselves questions from other contests/olympiads_."Indeed.If you can show me a source of this problem apart from Brilliant,I shall concede.Setting that aside,not mentioning any context and copying a question from another site where it is a live challenge _can_ be called abusing MSE.And from what I can see,this problem was shared by Best of Algebra which almost never forgets to cite the original source.

Comment: http://www.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/contests/past_contests/2012/2012CayleyContest.pdf        <-- Look here. This is the 2012 Cayley Contest for grade 10 and look at the last question #25. Now look here Brilliant: https://brilliant.org/community-problem/fine-with-five/?group=X4LjphhuFVK0  Clearly they are the same questions. Now this doesn't for all Brilliant questions but a number of them are from AMC,AIME,CEMC and some other contests/olympiads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\prod_{n=0}^{248}\frac{33+8n}{29+8n}=\prod_{n=0}^{248}\left(1+\frac4{8n+29}\right)\simeq\prod_{n=0}^{248}\left(1+\frac4{8n+28}\right)=\prod_{n=0}^{248}\left(1+\frac1{2n+7}\right)=$$

$$=\prod_{n=0}^{248}\left[1+\frac1{2(n+3)+1}\right]=\prod_{k=3}^{251}\left(1+\frac1{2k+1}\right)=\prod_{k=3}^{251}\frac{2k+2}{2k+1}=\prod_{k=3}^{251}\frac{k+1}{k+\frac12}=\frac5{16}\prod_{k=0}^{251}\frac{k+1}{k+\frac12}$$

$$=\frac5{16}\cdot\frac{\Gamma(253)}{\Gamma\left(252+\frac12\right)}\cdot\sqrt\pi=\frac5{16}\cdot\frac{252!}{504!\cdot2^{-504}\cdot(252!)^{-1}\cdot\sqrt\pi}\cdot\sqrt\pi=\frac5{16}\cdot2^{504}\cdot{504\choose252}^{-1}\simeq$$

$$\simeq\frac5{16}\cdot2^{504}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{252\pi}}{2^{504}}=\frac5{16}\cdot6\sqrt{7\pi}=\frac{15}8\sqrt{7\pi}\simeq8.8$$

In the above calculations, we've used the famous [multiplication formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_theorem#Gamma_function-Legendre_function) for the [Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Properties), as well as the well-known approximation for the [central binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient#Properties).

Comment: What you have done here is impressive. It at the very least is a way I can understand of solving this problem. Henry's approach was more accurate in terms of the approximation but your method is more systematic. Both solutions yield the same answer. Although the only sad thing is that I haven't really covered the Multiplication Theorem for the Gamma function yet so I'll have to do that xD

Answer (score 3):

I assume you cannot use a calculator, but can do simple division by hand and spot whether a number is between $8^2$ and $9^2$.

If you think $\dfrac{x+2}{x-2} \le \sqrt{\dfrac{x+4}{x-4}}$ is a reasonable approximation then your calculation becomes less than but close to $\displaystyle  \Bigg \lfloor \sqrt{ \frac{2019}{27} } \Bigg \rfloor$. The approximation is quite good here: it gives $\lfloor 8.6474\ldots  \rfloor$ rather than the correct $\lfloor 8.6357\ldots  \rfloor$.

You can do something similar for a lower bound: for example $\dfrac{x+4}{x} \ge \sqrt{\dfrac{x+8}{x}}$, so a lower bound is $\displaystyle  \Bigg \lfloor \sqrt{ \frac{2021}{29} } \Bigg \rfloor = \lfloor 8.3480\ldots \rfloor$.

So your answer is $8$.

Comment: Where did you get the floor(sqrt(2019/27)) from? Also how did you think of this approximation?

Comment: My aim was to get most of the numerators and denominators to cancel as in $\sqrt{\frac{35}{27} \times \frac{43}{35} \times \frac{51}{43} \times \cdots \times \frac{2011}{2003} \times \frac{2019}{2011}}$

Comment: Firstly I'm not abusing anything. Many of the questions on Brilliant are themselves questions from other contests/olympiads. One number theory question that I just solved was from a contest I wrote in grade 10. Secondly I ask for help for questions that I am having trouble with but I try my best to do any question independently and if I encounter trouble, I ask. I don't just take answers and use them for my benefit...Also I always site Brilliant for any questions that I ask but for the last 2 questions I didn't keep that in mind.